# mod() in PL/SQL returns an unexpected value

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

In PL/SQL, the `MOD()` returns some unexpected values. `MOD(23,2)` which is expected to return `1` actually returns `0`.

`MOD(29,2)` also returns `0`, I think the problem is that it uses the float values.

Is there any alternative to `MOD()`?

Comment: `mod(23,2)` returns 1 for me in both Oracle SQL and PL/SQL. Is this specific to one of the desktop applications you tagged? A reproducible test case would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative ?

Mod is:

```
x - y * floor(x/y)
```

so:

```
23 - 2 * 11 = 1 --(23/2 = 11,5 --> 'round down' = 11)
29 - 2 * 14 = 1 --(29/2 = 14,5 --> 'round down' = 14)
```

Good to know:

> The function to 'round up' is CEIL, but it generates an integer.
>
> The function to 'round down' is FLOOR, but it too generates an integer.
>
> The function to 'round nearest' is ROUND, and it allows you to specify a number of decimal places (dp).
>
> Note that CEIL rounds to an integer; to round to 2 dp, you'd have to multiply by 100, use CEIL, and divide by 100.